# How to route URLs with parameters in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, url-parameters

i'm new with ASP MVC3.
And i need to pass paramters to controller from my view

**viewgrid.aspx**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h3>
        GridView DataBind
    </h3>
    <asp:Label ID="Message" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IdGroupe" HeaderText="Group ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IdFichier" HeaderText="File ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NomFichier" HeaderText="File Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateHeureAjout" HeaderText="Adding Date" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Download" DataNavigateUrlFields="IdFichier,IdGroupe" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\Home\Download.aspx?IdF={0}&IdG={1}"
                HeaderText="Click To Download" Target="About" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
        public ActionResult viewgrid(string id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Download(string IdF, string IdG)
        {
            SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("Server=****;User=****;Pwd=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Fichier.NomFichier FROM Fichier WHERE Fichier.IdFichier ='" + IdF + "' AND Groupe.IdGroupe='" + IdG + "'");
            cnx.Open();
            SqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (r.Read())
            {
                string Nfichier = r.GetString(0);
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile("~/FileUploaded/" + Nfichier + "", @"c:\" + Nfichier + "");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

**Site.master**

```
<div id="Div1">
    <ul id="Ul1">
        <li>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
        <li>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
        <li>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "viewgrid", "Home")%></li>
        <li>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Download", "Home", new{iIdF={0}&IdG={1}})%></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But my server can't recognize the url passed, i know it's a routing matter but i can't find solution to this.

Comment: Edited out your password in the connection string. Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection, please [educate yourself](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html).

Comment: thanks, i just forget about it.

Comment: make sure of parameters names in your view , you wrote 'iIdF' and it should be 'IdF'. and remove the curly braces {0} to be "0"

Comment: @mohamed-farrag , what i expect is when i click on download link,my page should redirect to download Action in Home controller and download requested file

Answer (score 0):

Your Download action will handle only POST requests because of HttpPost attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Download(string IdF, string IdG)
```

Html.ActionLink generates  links. Browser sends GET request when link is clicked. Remove the [HttpPost] attribute to handle GET requests too.

Comment: no, you should replace {0} and {1} with some real values from Model.

Comment: i just replace it but no chance

Comment: did the link rendered correctly (check the resulting web page source) ? what happens when you click it?

Comment: Normally when i click on that link, my file should be downloaded and i'll be redirected to index Action but nothing happens here i'm at the same page and no download happen

Comment: did you checked the real url generated for link? is it correct? what happens when you just navigating to that url in browser?